# Merge overlapping image in ios

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to make a single image by selecting random images as per the given string. For that, I am writing the below code and it works perfectly fine:

```
int count=self.txtFld.text.length;
self.imgView3.image=nil;

UIButton *btn=(UIButton*)sender;
  if(btn.tag==1)
   {

    NSLog(@"Blackaddr Btn Clicked..");

    int i=0;
    while (i<count) {
        UIImage *img=self.imgView1.image;
        CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.imgView3.image.size.width+img.size.width-10, img.size.height);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

        [self.imgView3.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imgView3.image.size.width, self.imgView3.image.size.height)];
        [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(self.imgView3.image.size.width-10,0,img.size.width, size.height)];
        UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        self.imgView3.image = finalImage;
        [self.imgView3 setFrame:CGRectMake(self.imgView3.frame.origin.x, self.imgView3.frame.origin.y, finalImage.size.width, finalImage.size.height)];
        i++;
    }
}
```

Now I want to overlap those images, i.e. second image should be behind the first image, and place that Image in center.